# Multidimensional C Arrays

Tags: c

I have four arrays that contains some values. Another array should contain all these four arrays like shown in the code:

```
static const long ONE_COLOR[2] = { RGB_BLACK, RGB_WHITE };
static const long TWO_COLOR[4] = { RGB_WHITE, RGB_RED, RGB_GREEN, RGB_BLUE };
static const long THREE_COLOR[8] = { RGB_BLACK, RGB_RED, RGB_GREEN, RGB_BLUE,
    RGB_CYAN, RGB_YELLOW, RGB_MAGENTA, RGB_WHITE };
static const long FOUR_COLOR[16] = { RGB_WHITE, RGB_RED, RGB_GREEN, RGB_BLUE,
    RGB_CYAN, RGB_YELLOW, RGB_MAGENTA, RGB_DARK_RED, RGB_DARK_GREEN,
    RGB_DARK_BLUE, RGB_LIGHT_BLUE, RGB_LIGHT_GREEN, RGB_ORANGE, RGB_LIME,
    RGB_PINK, RGB_LILA };

//this array should contain all other arrays
static const long COLOR_ARRAY = {ONE_COLOR,TWO_COLOR, THREE_COLOR,
    FOUR_COLOR };
```

My problem is to access the values in the array. I thought I can receive the value of `RGB_BLACK` with `COLOR_ARRAY[0][0]`. I tried it with some pointer constructions, but it doesn't work neither :(

Comment: Why isn't `COLOR_ARRAY` declared as an *array*? You call it "array" in the comments. You used `ARRAY` in the variable name. But it is declared as an ordinary non-array variable. Why? You do know that array declaration requires `[]`, don't you? So, where's `[]` in `COLOR_ARRAY` declaration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want an array of pointers to arrays.

```
static const long *const COLOR_ARRAY[4] = {
    ONE_COLOR, TWO_COLOR, THREE_COLOR, FOUR_COLOR
};
```

Both `const` are recommended: the first `const` means that this is a pointer to constant arrays, the second `const` means that this array of pointers is, itself, constant.

You can access the elements as you'd think, so `COLOR_ARRAY[1][3] == RGB_BLUE`, et cetera.

#### Note

I am being a little sloppy with terminology.  You are not actually getting pointers to arrays but pointers to the first element in each array.  For most operations, in C, an array and a pointer to the first element are interchangeable.

Comment: m( I thought to complicated. Thanks for your hint! :)

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII it does exactly what it ought to do — whether your expectations are up to the task is another matter. :)

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: One could use that reason to argue that no programming language should exist, because programs never do what you want, only what you specify.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean

```
static const long COLOR_ARRAY[] = {ONE_COLOR,TWO_COLOR, THREE_COLOR, FOUR_COLOR };
```

You don't have `[]` in your version.

Answer (score 0):

you can define COLOR_ARRAY like this:

```
static const long* COLOR_ARRAY[4] = {ONE_COLOR,TWO_COLOR, 
                                     THREE_COLOR,FOUR_COLOR };
```

now you should be able to use:

```
COLOR_ARRAY[0][0]
```

Comment: m( I thought to complicated. Thanks for your hint! :)

Answer (score -1):

You can combine arrays like this:

```
first[3] = { 11, 17, 23 };
second[3] = { 46, 68, 82 };

combo[2][3] = {
         { 11, 17, 23 },{ 46, 68, 82 }};
```

I shamelessly copied this example from here:
http://rapidpurple.com/blog/tutorials/c-tutorials/programming-in-c-array-of-arrays/

Check it out!

Best regards -Tom

Comment: This is hardly helpful, and violates the original license on the code you posted.